# Recovering BUFFALO 3TB USB drive

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive

I went into a problem mounting a Buffalo 3TB external drive in Linux, formatted as EXT4.
It failed to mount after I reboot on my Desktop PC running MINT on Dell Inspiron.

Any help or pointers to much appreciated!

There is relevant dmesg log:

```
[  339.478808] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  339.495134] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0411, idProduct=0235
[  339.495144] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  339.495149] usb 4-2: Product: HD-GDU3
[  339.495153] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: BUFFALO INC.
[  339.495157] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 0000010200009594
[  339.571016] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  339.571095] scsi4 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[  339.571404] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  340.572245] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     BUFFALO  HD-GDU3          0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  340.572769] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  340.573186] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 732566646 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[  340.573475] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  340.573482] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 33 00 00 08
[  340.573751] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  340.574196] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 732566646 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[  371.200969] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  376.220025] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  376.324043] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  381.343572] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  381.535795] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  381.535822] sd 4:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  381.535828] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[  381.535829] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  381.535830] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  381.535832] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  381.535833] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[  381.535838] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[  381.535840] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[  381.535884] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[  381.535895] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[  381.535912]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[  381.536011] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
[  381.536014] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  381.536015] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  381.536016] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  381.536064] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  381.536067] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  381.536069] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  381.536813] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880035d15500
[  381.536816] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880035d15540
[  381.772090] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  386.791504] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  386.895434] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  391.914952] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  392.799917] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  397.819140] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  397.923024] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  402.942706] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  403.827608] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  408.846871] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  408.950764] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  413.970350] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  414.855271] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  419.874393] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  419.978413] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  424.997902] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  425.102099] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  425.362480] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  430.381784] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  430.485809] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  435.505372] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  436.390293] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  441.409360] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  441.513428] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  446.533075] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  447.417970] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  452.437115] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  452.541153] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  457.560694] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  458.445633] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[  463.464756] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  463.568752] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[  468.588302] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  468.692428] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  468.952574] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  473.976000] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  474.080030] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  479.099593] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  479.527954] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  484.547409] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  484.651448] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  489.671021] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  490.555968] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  495.575230] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  495.679115] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  500.698641] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  501.583668] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  506.602784] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  506.706825] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  511.726476] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found Buffalo products to be fairly cheap - cheap as in poorly made.  Try taking the drive out of the enclosure and hooking it up directly to your computers SATA connector and see if it mounts.  If it does, then the enclosure is borked.

You could also hook the drive up to a USB to SATA adapter as well.